# Data structure converting order sorting from list to set

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

basically, my defines this

```
nodes = ['Unix', 'BSD', 'Linux']
```

and when I try this

```
print(set(nodes))
```

I expect the result of it

```
{'Unix', 'BSD', 'Linux'}
```

but I got this

```
{'BSD', 'Linux', 'Unix'}
```

I don't want to break order of nodes is there good way for it?

Comment: Sets are not ordered.  To maintain order (simply), use lists or tuples.

Comment: that's my homework, so I have to output as set. Is there other way to...

Comment: What exactly does your homework ask you to do?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't have both order and a set (unless you use the [`OrderedSet` recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/), which I doubt was asked in a homework problem).  Make sure it's clear what the problem is asking.  Perhaps it means, "make a set from duplicate items and then order the results"  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sets` and `Dictionaries` are **not ordered** as they are `hash` based, so depending on what the input is, a `hash` value is calculated to associate your given element with a key. That's why access to a dictionary or set is fast `O(1)` but if you need ordered data, it might not be the best choice.

So you probably are trying to get rid of duplicates by creating a set? Instead you can use an`OrderedDict` and access the `keys` to get a unique list.

```
from collections import OrderedDict


nodes = ['Unix', 'BSD', 'Linux']
uniques = OrderedDict((x, True) for x in nodes).keys()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options :

first option:

use ordered dict:

As suggested by @user1767754 :

```
from collections import OrderedDict


nodes = ['Unix', 'BSD', 'Linux']
uniques = OrderedDict((x, True) for x in nodes).keys()
```

Second method keep track of index and values:

so first create a dict with index,values :

```
nodes = ['Unix', 'BSD', 'Linux']


order={}
for i,j in enumerate(nodes):
    order[i]=j

print(order)
```

it will give:

```
{0: 'Unix', 1: 'BSD', 2: 'Linux'}
```

Now do your stuff like converting list to set or whatever you want and at last convert again to list something like this:

```
new=[]
for i in set(nodes):
    for k,j in order.items():
        if i==j:
            new.insert(k,j)

print(new)
```

Now it will give:

```
['Unix', 'BSD', 'Linux']
```